# Convert curl command to invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm trying to convert next curl command to invoke-restmethod

```
curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -H 'X-Requested-With:ApiExplorer' 'https://LOCATION' -d 'action=fetch&id=1234567&output_format=CSV' > .\export.csv
```

But i'm stuck with the `action=fetch&id=1234567&output_format=CSV'` part.

Anyone has an idea

Comment: `-ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and pass the action in the URI

Answer (score 0):

You pass the body/data via a dictionary as here below:

```
$credentials = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("user:password"))

$headers = @{
    'X-Requested-With' = 'ApiExplorer'
    'Authorization' = "Basic $credentials" 
}

$body = @{
    action = 'fetch'
    id = '1234567'
    output_format = 'CSV'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'POST' -URI 'https://LOCATION' -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded  -OutFile export.csv
```

Comment: I used your code but got an error:

Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Any thoughts with that?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the url and/or authentication.